# ToString abstract operation: least significant digit not uniquely determined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm reading [the ECMAScript abstract operation ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1). In Step 5 (*m* is the number we want to convert to a string):

> 5. Otherwise, let *n*, *k*, and *s* be integers such that *k* ≥ 1, 10^(*k*−1) ≤ *s* < 10^*k*, the Number value for *s* × 10^(*n*−*k*) is *m*, and *k* is as small as possible. Note that *k* is the number of digits in the decimal representation of *s*, that *s* is not divisible by 10, and that **the least significant digit of *s* is not necessarily uniquely determined by these criteria**.

I can't figure out in which case the least significant digit of s would not be uniquely determined. Any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is - as always with floating point math - rounding at the edge of the available precision.

Let's take `s = 7011750883285835`, `k=16` and some `n` (let's say `n=0`). Now determining `m`, we'll get the floating point number 0x3FE67006BD248487 (somewhere around `0.70117508832858355…`). However, we could also have chosen `s = 7011750883285836` and it would be equal to `m` as well.

The point is that if we had converted the double to decimal representation exactly, we would've gotten `0.701175088328583551167128007364`. That is much longer than necessary (and implies higher precision than available), so the `ToString` algorithm specifies to make a decimal representation of `m` with the least amount of siginificant digits ("*`k` is as small as possible*") that still parses to the number `m` we want. Sometimes, we can both round up or round down to get that, and both ways are allowed.

Comment: How I got to that example? I just hit `Math.random()` until I got some number with a lot significant digits.

Comment: Are you saying that the least significant digit of s is not necessarily uniquely determined by these criteria because of the rounding operations of the Number type not to the ToString operation?

Comment: @welcome Yes. Or rather, that base 2 is just too different from base 10.